# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string not working with format in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am uploading the data in table like this `2016-10-17T00:00:00+05:30` and while fetching the data into variable I am using it like this `V_FINALSRDATE := cur_r.FINAL_SR_DATE`

So while executing it, I am getting the error as `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`.

So I tried like this

`V_FINALSRDATE := TO_DATE(cur_r.FINAL_SR_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy');`

Please suggest what needs to be changed and updated.

Comment: The string literal you give to TO_DATE to use as format model must match the actual string you are trying to convert to date. In your case, that model seems to be `'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzr'` - and it is not a "date" format, it is a "timestamp with time zone". What are you trying to achieve - do you want to discard the time zone information? Do you realize that you are losing information if you do that?

Comment: What data type is the column `FINAL_SR_DATE`?

Answer (score 1):

`2016-10-17T00:00:00+05:30` does not match the format `dd-mm-yyyy` and it has a time zone so it will not work converting it to a date.

You should be storing it in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type:

```sql
DECLARE
  V_FINALSRDATE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
  -- create a cur_r cursor with FINAL_SR_DATE column.
BEGIN
  V_FINALSRDATE := TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(cur_r.FINAL_SR_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM');
END;
/
```

If you want to convert it to a `DATE` then you can use something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  V_FINALSRDATE DATE;
  -- create a cur_r cursor with FINAL_SR_DATE column.
BEGIN
  V_FINALSRDATE := CAST(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(cur_r.FINAL_SR_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
    -- AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' -- Optionally, convert the date to a common time zone.
    AS DATE
  );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d5314639c0fdbb7eba1e05b9ffdc8552)*

Comment: It can be converted to a date (using `SUBSTR` first, to remove the time zone); in general, that's just unwise - but the OP can clarify.

Comment: @mathguy Use `CAST` to convert from a timestamp with time zone to a date. Depending on requirements, either with or without converting to a common time zone.